# What is the name of photographed retaining clip?

Tags: key

Context: 95 Acura Glove compartment handle, latch and key cylinder.

The dark ring pins the arm to the keyed-cylinder.  The goal is to remove the cylinder to reveal the 4 digit "key cut code".

1. What is the name of the beveled-dark-annual retaining ring?
2. What is the method to remove the ring without damaging it so it may be reused?
3. Bonus round: What is a different name for the open retaining clip photographed at 2 O'clock

It would be useful to have two different names to differentiate  the two retaining rings.

The hope is that experience can help with the second question.

Click on the photo see it full high resolution:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glarks' calls them an "[Internal Tooth Starlock Push On Locking Washers Speed Clips Fasteners](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076D3FZM4)" ... yah, a mouthful.

To remove them, gently pry around the outside with *little* lifts of a small/thin flat tip screwdriver, going around and around until it is removed. Replacement is a stiff push right back into place.

The split ring to the upper right is usually called an "e-ring" or "e-clip" retainer ... because they look like an "E" I guess.

Comment: The "e-ring" is shaped like the Euro symbol ... or is it the other way around??

Comment: @paulster nice find on AMZN with the Starlock lock washers.   Nice to see that you understood the purpose of the question is to be able to search AMZN or the like to find the specific part.

Comment: @gatorback - It took me a few tries to actually figure out what it was called ... my Google-Fu is weak sauce this morning.

Comment: @Paulster.  The force is strong in this one.    The effort is appreciated.  Credit awarded

Answer (score 2):

1. locking clip but can be called other names,
2. to remove gently prise each ear in turn until it comes off
3. that is a circlip aka "jesus clip" as in "ping - Jesus where did that go?"...

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were serious about "Jesus clip" so to my surprise Google returned https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circlip    Good one!

Comment: @gatorback common term when I did my apprenticeship and still used in many branches of engineering - experience pays off.